# Style for checking multiple elements in a Python sequence

Tags: python, coding-style

I frequently find myself writing code like this:

```py
tupla = (1, 2, 3, 4)
if (1 in tupla) and (4 in tupla):
    ...
```

Is there any Pythonic way to write this more compactly, without typing `tupla` twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if all(x in tupla for x in list_of_x):
```

or

```
if set(list_of_x).issubset(set(tupla)):
```

The first one will stop as soon as the first `x` is not in `tupla`. The second one will create both sets in any case.

Comment: Now I will use the second option, but the first one will come handy when `list_of_x` is very long.

Answer (score 2):

What your code is asking is essentially

> Is [1, 4] a *subset* of `tupla`?

You can express this question directly:

```
In [14]: set([1, 4]).issubset(tupla)
Out[14]: True

In [15]: set([1, 4, 7]).issubset(tupla)
Out[15]: False
```

or, more concisely:

```
In [18]: set([1, 4]) <= set(tupla)
Out[18]: True

In [19]: set([1, 4, 7]) <= set(tupla)
Out[19]: False
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wish I could accept multiple answers as valid.